# Ubuntu with SuPHP and Wordpress - default perms of .htaccess file gives Apache 500 Error

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu, wordpress, php5, suphp

Wordpress creates the .htaccess file with 600 file permissions (when permalinks are configured, etc.). I had to give it 655 before SuPHP would allow the homepage to load. I thought any files should be read as the user with SuPHP so I'm a bit puzzled here. I'm trying to replicate a shared hosting environment so non-developers  and setup CMS'es without difficulty so this is a showstopper for me. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to chmod .htaccess to 755 in order for it to work, otherwise you will still experience this issue. If you need to do that automatically for files created by apache, please check the next link:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/428416/setting-the-umask-of-the-apache-user

Comment: Obviously asking a non-dev to chmod their files won't help me. I've read a bit about masks. Can I configure one so that files created by the webserver are given 755 permissions by default?

Comment: I've added a comment. Please check if that helps.